# 123456789=1 problem

Tags: mathematics

Insert multiplication and division operators and parentheses into the following sequence to make the equation true.

Note that you can combine digits to form numbers, such as 1 and 2 to make 12, or 4 and 5 to make 45, but **you can't alter the order of the sequence.**

> 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 = 1

Comment: Doesn't seem to be a duplicate - this requires only multiplication and division, the other allowed any operators. Note that it's super easy with +/- : 1-2+3+4-5-6+7+8-9 = 1

Answer (score 19):

$$12 \times (3/4)/56 \times 7 \times 8/9 = 1$$